# SQL Server 2008 R2 Comma Delimited field vs a new table, advantages and disadvantages?

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I need to keep record of payments made against invoices. I have a payment table with a couple of fields. I need to store the invoices that were used in a certain payment. The payment to invoice relation is one to many. I can't change that. Do I create a field that stores the invoices delimited with a comma, or do I make a new table to store these invoices in?

Note: when I speak of an invoice, I am only referring to the invoice number (it's unique identifier).

What are the advantages and disadvantages of either approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Except for not being normalized at all (not even [1NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_form) that states that an attribute (column) needs to have *distinct* values, i.e. not several), there are many issues regarding - indexing, joining, querying and more with a "comma delimited field".

In short - you make a new table to store these invoices in.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use separate table and refer the key column. The advantages are

1. Easy to query
2. Performance improvement
3. Index creation
4. Easy to read and much more...

For more details read about - normalization.